# React JS sort json by date in UTC format

Tags: json, reactjs, sorting

I am using react JS to fetch some data from and API endpoint and then display it.
I want to sort it by date and time before displaying it.
Data looks like this when it's fetched:

```
{
  "2021-03-09T07:47:24.897Z[UTC]": "Something happened",
  "2021-03-09T07:48:12.256Z[UTC]": "Test event",
  "2021-03-09T08:04:49.484Z[UTC]": "Warning",
  "2021-03-09T07:08:15.714Z[UTC]": "Test event 2",
  "2021-03-09T07:47:24.736Z[UTC]": "Something bad happened 2"
}
```

I cannot change this json structure. I need to sort this by date and time and display in this format `YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss`

My function to do this looks like this:

```
formatDate(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => moment(a.obj).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss') - moment(b.obj).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'))
}
```

Then I do the following to the fetched json object:

```
console.log(this.formatDate(json));
```

Doing so returns the following:

```
0: "2021-03-09T07:47:24.897Z[UTC]"
1: "2021-03-09T07:48:12.256Z[UTC]"
2: "2021-03-09T08:04:49.484Z[UTC]"
3: "2021-03-09T07:08:15.714Z[UTC]"
4: "2021-03-09T07:47:24.736Z[UTC]"
```

Returned dates are not sorted. How do I make sure these returned sorted?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => new Date(a.replace("\[UTC\]", "")) - new Date(b.replace("\[UTC\]", "")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no `obj` property in your json.
2. There is no need to apply `format`, as the value becomes String. We can just compare the moment object.
3. The "[UTC]" inside the key is not standard date format, which leads to warning

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

You may try following snippet which fix above points:

```js
$(function () {
  
  let json = {
  "2021-03-09T07:47:24.897Z[UTC]": "Something happened",
  "2021-03-09T07:48:12.256Z[UTC]": "Test event",
  "2021-03-09T08:04:49.484Z[UTC]": "Warning",
  "2021-03-09T07:08:15.714Z[UTC]": "Test event 2",
  "2021-03-09T07:47:24.736Z[UTC]": "Something bad happened 2"
  };
  console.log("Sorted result:");
  console.log(formatDate(json));
});
// better to name it as sortDate
function formatDate(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => moment(a.replace("\[UTC\]","")) - moment(b.replace("\[UTC\]","")));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Funny thing is I kept looking at this [UTC] bit and it never occurred to me that's not a standard UTC date. I knew it wasn't but I never thought of removing it. Thanks a lot, I used your suggestion to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear by your function if you want to format a date, or sort it like your question asks, but you can directly compare datetime strings for the sorting, i.e. `dateA.localeCompare(dateB)`.

```
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB))
);
```

Convert the object into an array of key-value pairs and sort the array by the key values, then convert the array of key-value pairs back into an object.

If you need to do any format conversions then you should do this via a map operation, i.e. you map an array of keys from one format to another.

To convert to a UTC time:

```
moment.utc(key.replace("[UTC]", "")).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss')
```

```js
const data = {
  "2021-03-09T07:47:24.897Z[UTC]": "Something happened",
  "2021-03-09T07:48:12.256Z[UTC]": "Test event",
  "2021-03-09T08:04:49.484Z[UTC]": "Warning",
  "2021-03-09T07:08:15.714Z[UTC]": "Test event 2",
  "2021-03-09T07:47:24.736Z[UTC]": "Something bad happened 2"
};

const sortedData = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB))
);

console.log(sortedData);

const mappedData = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(sortedData).map(([key, value]) => [
    moment.parseZone(key.replace("[UTC]", "")).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'),
    value
  ])
);

console.log(mappedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're right, I might have described the issue wrong. I want to sort and change the format but the issue I was having was with sorting only. I got it working now. Thanks for your input mate.

Comment: @davidb I was editing right as you must've been reviewing. MomentJS doesn't handle time zones well, and I was adding in the date format mapping. Should help clarify a bit more. Cheers.